# How to display an empty line at the end of a code sample on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, markdown, code-formatting

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824491) that I asked, I wanted to display a blank line at the end of the data in code tags. But I was not able to do that in the normal way.

Is there a workaround or is it simply not possible at all?

I want to display something like this:

```
some code
<empty line>
some more code
<empty line>
```

**Problem is that the last  gets stripped from the code tags!**

Comment: I don't see what the purpose of that is

Comment: @Earlz: my paragraph ends are marked by an empty line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
this.blankLastLine = true;
```

Source:

```
<pre><code>this.blankLastLine = true;

</code></pre>
```

Comment: uniformity => better!

Answer (score 2):

```
This might not have worked.
‍
```

I don't imagine I know why you would have an empty line at the end, but if you really need them, you can try to use a character which doesn't necessarily display. For example, on my screen, this is a blank line at the end.

Real "blank" lines are not possible as the end of a code block is determined by the presence of non-blank characters.

Comment: That character is not exactly invisible...

Comment: its invisible to me! how did you do it?

Comment: got it! `U+200D`

Comment: Ahh, U+200D is the "magic wand" character? On some computers (Robert's and mine for instance) it displays like ... a magic wand ... but on other computers, it is completely invisible. Sweet!